# The specified condition for while loop has been met but it won't stop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a Tic-Tac-Toe game using python turtle, below is a small portion of function "choose".

```
snapshot = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

List "snapshot" is not inside a function.

```
def choose():
    which_box = input('Which box? 1-9:')
    draw_xo = input('x or o?')

    if which_box == '1':
        if draw_xo == 'x':
            x(third / 2, third / 2)  # Function X has coordinates as parameters
            snapshot[0] = 'x'  # Assign x to an index in snapshot
        elif draw_xo == 'o':
            o(third / 2, third / 2)
            snapshot[0] = 'o'
```

So after the a user gets three boxes in a row to win, the loop inside the function below keeps running, even though a condition for winning has been met. Inside this function is where the problem is.

```
def check_if_won():
    # Create variables to store the various win conditions (cases)
    c1 = snapshot[0:2] == 'x' 
    c2 = snapshot[3:5] == 'x'  
    c3 = snapshot[6:8] == 'x' 
    c4 = snapshot[0] == 'x' and snapshot[3] == 'x' and snapshot[6] == 'x' 
    c5 = snapshot[1] == 'x' and snapshot[4] == 'x' and snapshot[7] == 'x'  
    c6 = snapshot[2] == 'x' and snapshot[5] == 'x' and snapshot[8] == 'x' 
    c7 = snapshot[0] == 'x' and snapshot[4] == 'x' and snapshot[8] == 'x'  
    c8 = snapshot[2] == 'x' and snapshot[4] == 'x' and snapshot[6] == 'x' 
    c9 = snapshot[0:2] == 'o'  
    c10 = snapshot[3:5] == 'o'  
    c11 = snapshot[6:8] == 'o' 
    c12 = snapshot[0] == 'o' and snapshot[3] == 'o' and snapshot[6] == 'o'  
    c13 = snapshot[1] == 'o' and snapshot[5] == 'o' and snapshot[7] == 'o'  
    c14 = snapshot[2] == 'o' and snapshot[5] == 'o' and snapshot[8] == 'o'  
    c15 = snapshot[0] == 'o' and snapshot[4] == 'o' and snapshot[8] == 'o'  
    c16 = snapshot[2] == 'o' and snapshot[4] == 'o' and snapshot[6] == 'o'  
    # Put variables in a list so I can iterate over them
    case_list = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16]
    for case in case_list:
        while case is False:
            choose()
    if case in case_list is True:  # This does not work
        print('Game over!')  # This never happens even when the conditions are true
```

I assigned each win condition to a variable so I can iterate over them in the for loop. Then I checked each variable to see if one of them is True.Why doesn't the above code work? Am I using the for loop wrong? Or maybe my goal is not achievable with the method I tried to use? I also tried writing it this way:

```
for case in case_list:
    while not case:
        choose()
    if case:  # I have learned putting "is True" is unnecessary here
        print('Game over!')
```

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: and where does the 'third' value come from?

Comment: third is a variable i assigned to length / 3. length is a user input. I used a variable for length / 3 to make the code more readable for myself. The code above is not the full thing, just only what i think is relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
for case in case_list:
    while case is False:
        choose()
```

This will pick the first value in the `case_list`, which has to be `c1`, and it will run `while` loop until this condition is true.

You need to replace `for...while...` loops, with simple `while` loop, that will check if there is any `True` in your `case_list`

```
while True not in case_list:
    choose()
```

This should work!

Comment: And keep in mind, that your choose() method should update not only snapshot[] list, but also case_list[]. Otherwise it will always have initial values (all False) in it and will never finish again.

Comment: How would I update case_list[] inside the choose() function?

Answer (score 0):

These statements and their `o` partners must *always* evaluate to `False`:

```
c1 = snapshot[0:2] == 'x' 
c2 = snapshot[3:5] == 'x'  
c3 = snapshot[6:8] == 'x'
```

You compare a 3-character slice of `snapshot` to a single character; these can *never* compare as equal.  Try the full match:

```
c1 = snapshot[0:2] == 'xxx' 
c2 = snapshot[3:5] == 'xxx'  
c3 = snapshot[6:8] == 'xxx'
```

Or perhaps use the `all` function

```
c1 = all(snapshot[i] == 'x' for i in range(0, 3) )
c2 = all(snapshot[i] == 'x' for i in range(3, 6) )
c3 = all(snapshot[i] == 'x' for i in range(6, 9) )
```